# Windows 10 pro 64 bit OS: Phoenix OS booting error: device descriptor read/64, error -71

Tags: windows

I have Windows 10 pro 64 bit OS, with Intel core 2 duo T5870 processor 2.0 ghz speed and 2 Gb ram. I tried to install phoenix OS but it says that I have 32 bit OS so download x86 phoenix OS but instead I Downloaded phoenix OS 3.0.5 and at the time of booting it showed an error that:

```
[.      0.134273]  ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, Evaluating  _PRS (20170728/pci_link-176)
[.      1.492032] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Detecting Phoenix OS...found at /dev/sda5
```

Comment: Could you make the question more clear? What are you attempting to do, and where can we help?

Comment: I wanted to download phoenix OS 3.0.5 version in windows 10 pro 64 bit OS so when I installed it and rebooted it then it showed the above error and did not open. So my problem is that I think I am not able to download 64 bit software and my pc is still a 32 bit OS as whenever I try to download phoenix OS it says that you have a 32 bit OS.

Comment: where did you install Phoenix OS? In a VM or in the physical machine? ` think I am not able to download 64 bit software` this is nonsense. You can download anything including binaries for other platforms because they're just binary data after all

Answer (score -1):

Of course, you can’t install 64-bit software on a 32-bit OS.

According to your hardware configurations, I suspect that you are using a 32-bit Windows 10(due to only 2 GB RAM). Please check your system properties

About error message usb "device descriptor read/64, error -71", look at this case below for a hint

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/usb-error-usb-2-4-device-descriptor-read-64-error-71-a-643022/

Comment: Intel Core 2 Duo T5870 is definitely a 64-bit CPU because all the core 2 series are 64-bit capable. In fact pretty much any Intel CPUs from Pentium 4 Prescott onward are 64-bit capable

Comment: So what should I do bro

Comment: I had installed phoenix OS in a 20 Gb disk partition